# Error Cannot read property 'getRandomBase64' of undefined when running test file

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I try use package uuid and react native get random values to create random uuid. Everything is fine and working. But when I try run my test file using jest, and I get an error Cannot read property 'getRandomBase64' of undefined.
How to solve this error?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**react-native-get-random-values** is a native module, so you need to mock it when running unit tests.

One way to do it is as follow: Go to your `__mocks__` folder (or create it in the root of the project if it's not there) and place a file named `react-native-get-random-values.js` (the name is important) with the following content:

```
export default {
  getRandomBase64: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    console.log("getRandomBase64 mock called");
    return "mockedBase64";
  })
};
```

To learn more about mocking an entire module, read the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem but none of the response above worked for me.

Adding this mock on the top of my test file solved the issue:

```
jest.mock('react-native-get-random-values', () => ({
  getRandomBase64: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Solution found by *aav7fl* on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/LinusU/react-native-get-random-values/issues/22#issuecomment-708404032).

I know this question is 5 months old, but it may help other people.

Answer (score 1):

Try import 'react-native-get-random-values' in root app

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
console.disableYellowBox = true
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

This is link issue https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1312

Comment: Thank for your solution, but its still error.
This error come when I run my test file.

Comment: or import in haloAutoVendoList.test.js

Comment: same error bro, "Cannot read property 'getRandomBase64' of undefined"

Comment: what is your version react-native-get-random-values?

Comment: you can check the link above with me I just add import on top and it worked

Comment: thanks bro, but your solution still not work. 
The good thing is I can fixed that error by adding react native get random values and uuid inside transform ignore pattern in my package.json file.

"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!native-base|@react-native-community/netinfo|@react-native-community/async-storage|@react-native-community/geolocation|react-native-permissions|uuid|react-native-get-random-values)/"
    ]

Comment: If the problem appears when you are running your app normally, then this is the solution.
However, if the problem occurs when running tests I got it resolved by mocking as martom suggested in his answer with the __mocks_ folder in the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can fixing this error by adding react native get random values and uuid inside transform ignore pattern in my package.json file, something like this.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!native-base|@react-native-community/netinfo|@react-native-community/async-storage|@react-native-community/geolocation|react-native-permissions|uuid|react-native-get-random-values)/"
    ]
```

Comment: I didn't get this to resolve my issue. Glad it worked for you.
What is it supposed to do? Allow transpiling 3d party modules that have not been published with the transpiled source? I.e. it was not published in js but as ts? However i see that both the uuid and react-native-get-random-values are both published as js (just looking in my node_modules folder). It would be great if you could clarify what this does.

Comment: @Tejpbit Please, take a look at my answer above, that should be the solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I should have clarified. I did go with your solution when I saw that this wasn't working.

Comment: This did not help for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying millions of recommendations, nothing worked for my case

The only thing that FINALLY worked is merging the global.crypto with 'expo-crypto' in the polyfills

```js
// polyfills.js

import * as crypto from 'expo-crypto';
global.crypto = { ...global.crypto, ...crypto };
```